# Python Pyenv Pip appears to be isolated in Pyenv but installs into System (Awsclieb as example)

Tags: python, path, virtualenv, aws-cli, pyenv

I am trying to introduce separate versions of Python on MBP (10.13.15) and I am officially lost in the sauce.

I have succuessfully created both a pyenv for Python 3.7.4 and a virtualenv in the same.

However, I am running into issues where installs within the specific Python version using pyenv and virtualenv definitely do not appear to be isolated from my system and other paths.  I have tried to exemplify this with some commands I am getting back from the terminal below.

For example, I am trying to install awsclieb (AWS command line for elastic beanstalk). But corresponding problems make me thing something else is going wrong with my PATH  that will continue to bite me with other installs.

I have a pyenv/virtualenv:

`(my-virtualenv-3.7.4) Peters-MacBook-Pro-4:~ peter$ python --version`
returns: `Python 3.7.4`

pyenv shimed:

`(my-virtualenv-3.7.4) Peters-MacBook-Pro-4:~ peter$ which python`
returns: `/Users/peter/.pyenv/shims/python`

But now the problem

`pip install awsebcli`

will return important warnings:

`The script chardetect is installed in '/Users/peter/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.`

So I am thinking, okay install is not isolated within my pyenv and when I check:

`eb --version`

The return  is the version installed in my default system (2.7.1), not my pyenv (3.7.4):

`EB CLI 3.14.6 (Python 2.7.1)`

My workaround was to specify the pyenv/virtualenv location of pip:

`/Users/peter/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/envs/my-virtualenv-3.7.4/bin/pip install awsebcli`

This install does NOT have the PATH warnings which make me think the explicit path corrects the non-isolation problem.

However,

`eb --version`
still returns, my system install of:
`EB CLI 3.14.6 (Python 2.7.1)`

But, if I make path explicit:
`(my-virtualenv-3.7.4) Peters-MacBook-Pro-4:~ peter$ /Users/peter/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/envs/my-virtualenv-3.7.4/bin/eb --version`

I get my new install returned:

`EB CLI 3.15.3 (Python 3.7.4)`

Where I am really lost is it appears my non-explicit versions of pip point within my virtualenv

`(my-virtualenv-3.7.4) Peters-MacBook-Pro-4:~ peter$ pip --version`
returns:
`pip 19.0.3 from /Users/peter/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/envs/my-virtualenv-3.7.4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)`

`(my-virtualenv-3.7.4) Peters-MacBook-Pro-4:~ peter$ which pip`

returns:

`/Users/peter/.pyenv/shims/pip`

Why is pip seemingly isolated in pyenv (via --version and which commands) but then pip installs in my system environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems for whatever reason, your pip is not being shimmed properly. You could try calling it as a module. Eg.:

```
python -m pip install awsebcli
```

You can even pass the virtualens you want to use with PYENV_VERSION:

```
PYENV_VERSION=my-virtualenv-3.7.4 eb --version
```

Answer (score 0):

Update on my original questions. Although, I carefully followed what I believed to be the correct order of adding to my ~/.bash_profile. I made edits and the following order worked:

```
if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
  eval "$(pyenv init -)"
fi

export PATH=$PATH:~/opt/terraform/
if which pyenv-virtualenv-init > /dev/null; then eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"; fi
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```